# Cant parse json in jquery

Tags: jquery, json

I am getting result `[object],[object]`, why I am not getting JSON data? Please correct me.

My jquery is

```
$.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "js/dropDown-json.js",
            dataType:"json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success:function(data){
                //alert(data.view);
                $.each(data.view, function(){
                    //alert(data.view.entityView[2]);

                    $("#selectFilter_dropdown ul li").append("<a href='#'>"+ data.view +"</a>");
                    });

                }
```

HTML is

```
<div class="dropDown_wrapper">
                    <div id="selectFilter_dropdown">
                        <ul>
                           <li>  </li> <!-- Fetching json data -->                            
                        </ul>                                                    
                </div>
```

JSON is

```
{
    "view" : [
{ "entityView":"None"}, 
{ "entityView":"Default Entity View"}, 
{ "entityView":"Doc View 1"},
{ "entityView":"Global Entity View"},
{ "entityView":"My Items View"}
]}
```

But the output is `[object],[object]`... may I know where am I wrong ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your [$.each](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) is wrong:

```
$.each(data.view, function(i, v){
    $("#selectFilter_dropdown ul li").append("<a href='#'>"+ v.entityView +"</a>");
});
```

v is the value of each item in view.

Answer (score 1):

Use following to get response in string format.

```
response = JSON.stringify(data.view)
```

and to use in your code to fill up `LI` use [jQuery each()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each) function, value will be `data.view.entityView`. like:

```
$(data.view).each(function(index, item){
    $("#selectFilter_dropdown ul li").append("<a href='#'>"+ item.entityView +"</a>");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

data.view is a javascript array not a string...

try this:

```
$.each(data.view, function(view){
    $("#selectFilter_dropdown ul li").append("<a href='#'>"+ view.entityView +"</a>");
});
```